# Put an event on a table row in vuejs

Tags: vue.js

Hi i have been looking for a simple answer to this question but cant seem to find one i have the spatie table plugin for my vue app which looks like this.

```
                <table-component id="table1" :data="[
                                         { firstName: 'John', birthday: '04/10/1940', songs: 72 },
                                         { firstName: 'Paul', birthday: '18/06/1942', songs: 70 },
                                         { firstName: 'George', birthday: '25/02/1943', songs: 22 },
                                         { firstName: 'Ringo', birthday: '07/07/1940', songs: 2 },
                                         ]" sort-by="songs" sort-order="asc">
                    <table-column show="firstName" label="First name"></table-column>
                    <table-column show="songs" label="Songs" data-type="numeric"></table-column>
                    <table-column show="birthday" label="Birthday" :filterable="false" data-type="date:DD/MM/YYYY"></table-column>
                </table-component>
```

I want to create a method that when you click a table row it pushes my router to a different page and passes the table row information to the next router page

```
this.$router.push('/analytic-one');
```

Any help or advice would be appreciated thank you.

Comment: Do you want to add it to a new row ?

<table-column show="next" label="Next></table-column>

Comment: No literally just want to push the router to a separate page when you click a row that would pass over the table rows information

Comment: Please edit your post and explain better what you're trying to achieve and what you have already tried.

Comment: There's currently an [open issue](https://github.com/spatie/vue-table-component/issues/15) in the repo about implementing this very thing. So you could contribute it yourself or wait until it's implemented.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways you could solve this.

But for the clicks themselves, in the [Documentation](https://github.com/spatie/vue-table-component#listeners) for spatie table component, which was updated after this question was asked.

> The table-component currently emits one custom event:
>
> @rowClick: is fired when a row is clicked. Receives the row data as it's event payload.

Which tells us that the row data is returned in the payload, so we can do

```
<table-component @rowClick="myHandlerMethod" ....
```

And in our methods object

```
methods: {
    myHandlerMethod: function (clickedItem) {
        console.log(clickedItem)
    }
}
```

And for sending the data to a new page, you could solve it in many ways.

You could use vuex to temporarily store the table information after clicking the table row, then push the router to the new page and fetch the data from the vuex state again.

Or you could use something like `$router.push('route?artistId=' + clickedItem.id)` and then do an ajax call to fetch data for that column again when the user lands on the new page, which is the clean way to do this. (this is pseudo code, look into vue router for the proper way of binding variables to the route.) This assumes you have an id in your data-set.

Or you could opt for using a modal instead, then you could do something like
`this.selectedItem = clickedItem` in the click handler.

Hope that gives you a general direction.